# Logged out redirect not working for cartthrob:add_to_cart tag

Tags: cartthrob, conditionals, redirects

I have add to cart buttons like this:

```
<a href="{entry_id_path='weekend-courses/add-to-cart'}" >Book now</a>
```

'weekend-courses/add-to-cart' contains only this:

```
{if logged_out}
  {redirect='account/login/return/weekend-courses/'}
{/if}

{if logged_in}
  {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart entry_id="{segment_3}" quantity="1" return="weekend-courses/checkout/{segment_3}"}
{/if}
```

Clicking the book now link adds an item to the cart and goes to weekend-courses/checkout/{segment_3} when I am logged-in AND when I am logged-out.

Changing to this

```
{if logged_out}
  {redirect='account/login/return/weekend-courses/'}
{/if}

{if logged_in}
  <p>Logged in</p>
{/if}
```

Works as expected.

Any ideas why this isn't working as expected?

Comment: Are you using pre-EE2.9?

Comment: Nope. It's EE 2.11.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive this is a parse order issue with ExpressionEngine, not anything CartThrob can change. I agree with [James's comment](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/36464/logged-out-redirect-not-working-for-cartthrobadd-to-cart-tag#comment37591_36464), that EE 2.9+ parse order might work better for this. You might consider adding your logic around the "book now" button, and using another template which just has "add to cart" logic.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with Switchee

```
{exp:switchee variable = "global:member_id" parse="inward"} 
    {case value="1"}
        {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart entry_id="{segment_3}" quantity="1" return="weekend-courses/checkout/{segment_3}"}
    {/case}
    {case value="0"}
        {redirect='account/login/return/weekend-courses/'}
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

That's working fine. Thanks for the suggestions James & Matt